# How can I enjoy the final boss battle in Xenoblade when the characters' levels are too high?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles

I've learned from various sources that the final battle in Xenoblade features a special quick-timed vision tag system, which doesn't get invoked if you out-level the boss by more than 5 levels, due to handicapping.

I'm thinking of downgrading the weapons/armors and going solo (by signaling the other party members to stop fighting), but not sure if it's going to work. Will it successfully bring me on par with the final boss? Is there any other way?

Comment: well the final boss is "lvl ???" so you might not have to worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

The final boss, despite being displayed as "Lvl ???", is actually around level 82 (or 83) if I remember correctly.

I'm not actually sure about the special visions since my party was about lvl 75-78 when I fought him, but I do know that if it's a level-based handicapping mechanic (like all the other handicaps, which are based on the enemy's colour - white, blue, yellow, red, etc. - in relation to you), then it really does only depend on your party's level (defined, I believe, by the level of the highest party member), and your nothing else - so changing your equipment or ordering others not to fight won't change anything.